# cannot insert an record into a table inside a LOOP statement with pgplsql (Redshift environment)

Tags: stored-procedures, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

I cannot insert an record into a table inside a LOOP statement with PL/pgSQL (Redshift environment); everything works except adding the `insert` statement; and the procedure cannot be created/modified with the `insert` statement inside the `LOOP` logic.

The compiling error is

```
SQL Error \[42601\]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
Where: SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "usp_ppv_process_cs_6months" near line 29
```

I tried to modify the procedure by adding the `insert` statement, but it just does not work; and a SQL Error 42601 appeared when trying to compile the procedure code.

```
create or replace  PROCEDURE aigdm.usp_ppv_process_cs_6months() AS $$
DECLARE
    po_nbr varchar(50);
    po_line_nbr varchar(50);
    due_date timestamp; 
    po_qty int; 
    po_amt_in_po_currency float8;
    rowcount int;
    target record; 
    open_po_cursor cursor for 
    SELECT
    wo_nbr
    ,po_line_nbr
    ,txn_date
    ,txn_qty
    ,po_amt_in_po_currency
    from
    aigdm.vw_aig_inventory_mrp
    where wo_nbr in ('257360CS','254358CS' );
BEGIN
    OPEN open_po_cursor; 
    po_nbr:= null;
    po_line_nbr := null;
    due_date := null; 
    po_qty := null; 
    po_amt_in_po_currency := null; 
     LOOP
        fetch open_po_cursor into po_nbr,po_line_nbr,due_date,po_qty,po_amt_in_po_currency;
        exit when not found;
        insert into aigdm.aig_bi_ppv_cs_6months (po_nbr) values (po_nbr); 
        commit;
    RAISE INFO 'a % at ', po_nbr; 
    END LOOP; 
    CLOSE open_po_cursor; 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: never ever name variables like column names , the database believes that you mean the column name not the variable use p_po_nbr  or such alike for variables

Comment: What a sql wizard, nbk! It IS the variable naming problem. now I DECLARE
 po_nbr1 varchar(50), then the code compiled, working like a charm. Thank you so much nbk. You made my day a plpgsql day.

Comment: Can I ask another question? why does this sql line statement not work?   <br/>                                                                 RAISE INFO 'at %   ', timestamp;

Comment: that i can not tell you,close this question and  ask  a new question. i would guess your query don't have any rows as result

Comment: how to close my question here, please? This issue has been resolved on my end.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use variable names that are equal to column names. Since you have a variable `po_nbr`, your `INSERT` statement

```
insert into aigdm.aig_bi_ppv_cs_6months (po_nbr) values (po_nbr)
```

leads to this prepared statement

```
insert into aigdm.aig_bi_ppv_cs_6months ($1) values ($1)
```

which is syntactically incorrect, since you cannot use a parameter for a column name.

Renaming the variable will fix the problem.

But the use of a procedure is quite unnecessary here. You could do the same thing much more efficiently with a single `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO aigdm.aig_bi_ppv_cs_6months (po_nbr)
SELECT wo_nbr
FROM aigdm.vw_aig_inventory_mrp
WHERE wo_nbr IN ('257360CS','254358CS' );
```